# Asymptotically logarithmic power series for $z\to 1$ with positive coefficients

Tags: asymptotics, power-series

Consider a power series $S(z)=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} a_i z^i$ which is analytic for $|z|<1$ and has non-negative coefficients $a_i$. If I know that for $q>p>0$ and $z\in (1-\varepsilon, 1)$ it holds $$ p(-\log(1-z))\leq S(z) \leq q(-\log(1-z)),$$ then it follows immediatley, that $$ S(z)\sim -\log(1-z)$$ as $z\to 1$. Motivated by [Analytic Combinatorics, Flajolet, Sedgewick](http://algo.inria.fr/flajolet/Publications/AnaCombi/book.pdf) I am wondering what I can say about the behaviour of the sequence $(a_i)_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$. I guess it should behave like $a_i\sim i^{-1}$ as $i\to\infty$, since otherwise the lower or upper bound should not be satisfied, but I do not succeed at doing a formal proof. How can I make this conclusion (if it is correct)?

Comment: I think the conclusion is not correct. Even if most of the $a_i$ behave as $i^{-1}$ a small but infinite number could be wildly different without affecting the behaviour. It should also be possible that most of the $a_i$ are zero but the remaining ones are big enough to still get the log asymptotitcs.